# Update with files won't submit laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, web

I'm working on a laravel project where I need file upload. I have successfully managed to get file upload for the create function working, but for the `edit()` and `update()` functions, it won't. The main problem is that the form won't submit. here is the import pits of my form:

```
<form action="{{route('ads.update', $ad->id)}}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageUpload" class="control-label col-md-4">@lang('image upload')</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        </div>
    </div><input type="submit" value="أضف التعديل" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-default">
</form>
```

Whenever I delete this section of code, the form submits and the `update()` works flawlessly

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageUpload" class="control-label col-md-4">@lang('image upload')</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    </div>
```

Things I've tried:

- Changing the enctype to put
- Changing the method from PATCH to PUT

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: But why it doesn't submit? It is returning an error of required images or something like that?
Can you see the POST result in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: how do i look?? I have developer mode enabled in my chrome but this is the first time I encounter this

Comment: in the network section

Comment: does nothing completely... no network requests would be made

Comment: One thing to note is that the `name="images[]"` should just be `name="images"` on your `input type="file"`. This is because the `multiple` attribute automagically sends an array to the server. Probably not your issue, but food for thought.

Comment: It has to be multiple because I want it similar to the create() method